# Welcome page in Visual Studio Code How to get it

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just downloaded [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and started playing with it.

The you tube [video here](https://youtu.be/DmbvejtiyNo?t=133) recommends Quick Tour Videos.

So the question is how can I see the welcome page on Visual Studio code. When ever I open now, I am not seeing it. Probably when you open for the first time, you are shown this. But once you close that how do I reopen it?

Comment: You might just want to use this link to the videos in the documentation section of the VSCode page: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/introvideos/overview

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You have to use the **command** palette (either press `F1` or click `View -> Command Palette...`), then start typing `Welcome` and select `Help: Welcome` option.

Comment: I don't see the command now. I think they removed the welcome screen.

Comment: That is weird because I can still see it inthe latest VSCode (1.10.1) and latest VSCode Insider (1.11.0)

Comment: It's now called the "Get Started" page. You can access it with the `Help: Get Started` option in the command palette

Comment: Now it's called "Get Started" page instead of "Welcome" page.

Comment: For me its still `Help: Welcome`. VS Code 1.76.2 on Linux.

Comment: Also still called Help: Welcome in VS Code 1.79.0 on macOS.

Answer (score 44):

This can now (May 2017) be accessed via the standard menu: `Help` -> `Welcome`

Comment: There should also be a checkbox to tick - "Show welcome page on startup", if you want it to show every time VSC is started.

Comment: Now it's called "Get Started" page instead of "Welcome" page.

Answer (score 20):

It looks like the name of the welcome page got changed into "Get Started". To open the "Get Started" page:
Click in the menu:

> Help -> Get Started

**Or** type in the command palette:

> ">Get Started"

Tested with:

> Version: 1.61.0-insider
> Commit: 5991e3c4b97eca5568069bf3e0910ab693ad3549
> Date: 2021-09-27T05:15:36.819Z
> Electron: 13.4.0
> Chrome: 91.0.4472.164
> Node.js: 14.16.0
> V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
> OS: Linux x64 5.14.2-arch1-2

Answer (score 20):

It is not showing because you probably accidentally unchecked the 'Show welcome page on startup' checkbox on the bottom of the welcome page.

From the menu: Help -> Get Started.

From command palette: Get Started.

To show it automatically when opening a new window check the 'Show welcome page on startup' checkbox on the bottom of the page.

Comment: **Help -> Get Started** worked for me, ty! I find it a bit misleading to call it a "Welcome" page when my only interest in it is it displays my half-dozen "recent" projects from which to make a choice, whenever I close my current project folder.

Answer (score 12):

To show welcome page on startup: User Settings > Workbench > Startup Editor > Select 'welcomePage'

Comment: This has changed.  It is now a setting called the "startup editor" and you set it to "welcomePage".

Answer (score 7):

Go to the 'Help' tab in the top menu and then select 'Get Started'. Look at the bottom of the page and click the checkbox below that says 'Show welcome page on startup'.

Answer (score 2):

**CMD + Shift + P**

Then search for

**Help:Welcome**

[image: Help: Welcome]

Answer (score 1):

remove `"workbench.startupEditor": "none"` from setting.json